# Insert method of a ManyToMany with attributes relationship

Tags: hibernate, refactoring, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping, cascade

I have a association table that has beyond the Foreign Keys another three attributes that I have to save.

With a common ManyToMany relationship I can manage this situation very simple with the Hibernate framework using some like this:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "tb_table1")
    public class Table1 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_table1", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @JoinTable(name = "ta_association_table", 
            joinColumns =@JoinColumn(name = "id_table1"), 
            inverseJoinColumns =@JoinColumn(name = "id_table2"))
    private List<Object2> object2List;

//more code
```

My doubt is where I can set the other attributes ?

I can't find this answer and this led me to another solution:

Association class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_association_table")
    public class AssociationTable implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idl",nullable=false)  
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_table1", nullable=false)
    private Table1 table1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_table2", nullable=false)
    private Table2 table2;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_att1", nullable=false)
    private Attribute1 att1;

    @Column(name="id_att2", nullable=false)
    private Attribute2 att2 = true;

    //getters and setters
```

The other classes are pretty much similar:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_table1")
public class Table1 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_table1", nullable=false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String description;

    private boolean status = true;

    //getters and setters
```

And finally my insert method:

```
public void insert(AssociationClass associationClass, List<Table2> table2List) {

   if (associationClass != null && associationClass.getTable1() != null) {

      if (table2List != null && table2List.size() > 0) {

         table1Service.insert(associationClass.getTable1());

            for (Table2 tbl2 : table2List) {

        AssociationClass newAC = new AssociationClass();
        newAC.setId(null);
        newAC.setAtt1(associationClass.getAtt1());
           newAC.setAtt2(associationClass.getAtt2);
        newAC.setAtt3(associationClass.getAtt3());
        newAC.setTable1(associationClass.getTable1());
           newAC.setTable2(tbl2);

        super.insert(newAC);
          }

    } 
    }

}
```

Particularly I don't like of this code because it isn't intuitive. I think that maintain this can turn into something difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible doing what you want. You have to create an intermediate class (just as you did) and put the attributes on it.

[Attributes on Many-to-Many relationships (Hibernate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476600/attributes-on-many-to-many-relationships-hibernate)

Comment: Thank you Genzotto. I read and I agree that it's not possible do this kind of thing automatically. What about the method? Do you think in some possibilities of refactor ?

Comment: I'm afraid ManyToMany relationships always generate methods like this