# @Manytomany add extra field with no join Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I created a @ManyToMany relation between two table, without have a relational entity through them. 
Something like this:

```
@Entity 
public class Category{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long categoryId;
}


@Entity 
public class Content {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "CONTENT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long contentId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name="CATEGORIES_CONTENTS",
        joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="CONTENT_ID", 
                        referencedColumnName="CONTENT_ID", 
                        nullable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="CATEGORY_ID", 
                        referencedColumnName="CATEGORY_ID", 
                        nullable = false)
    })
    private List<Category> categories;
}
```

Now, after the end of the project, I have the need to add an extra field in the relational table to handle a new feature.

Is it possible to do that, without create the related entity? I don't want to change a lot of things.

I already read this good article: [Can add extra field(s) to @ManyToMany Hibernate extra table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153409/manytomany-hibernate-question-can-add-extra-field)

but it isn't what I need.

Tanks a lot, Davide.

Comment: I'd be interested in an answer but not for hibernate specifically