# Multiple foreign key mapping

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to learn Hibernate and i can't solve a design problem. 
I have Head and Group Classes. I have generated two tables listed below using hibernate.

```
Table-Head
id, int4, primary key
name, varchar 50
description, varchar 250

Table-Group 
id, int4, primary key
name, varchar 25
description, varchar 250
```

I just want to ask how can i generate HeadAndGroup table which is listed below? I have tried to write HeadAndGroup as separate class but i can't handle it.

```
Table HeadAndGroup (Many to Many)
id , int4, primary key
head_id , int4, foreign key -> head table
group_id , int4, foreign key -> group table


**head_id, group_id pair will be unique
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `Collection<Head> heads` in your `Group` class with `@ManyToMany` annotation. Hibernate will then handle the `HeadAndGroup` table for you.

```
@ManyToMany(
    targetEntity=Head.class,
    cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}
)
public Collection getHeads() {
    return heads;
}
```

Have a look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/) for details.

Comment: Yes it creates table with head_id and group_id pairs. 
but i need one more  id (primary key) attribure. How can handle this?
Btw, is head_id and group_id pair unique?

Comment: You cannot add other columns to the hibernate generated table. To add another column, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1168740/643109