# How to add extra columns in many to many join table in hbm.xml : hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, rdbms, hbmxml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can add extra field(s) to @ManyToMany Hibernate extra table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153409/can-add-extra-fields-to-manytomany-hibernate-extra-table)

Here is my problem,is there any way to add extra columns in many to many join table using hbm.xml files in hibernate. Just like:

```
Create table employee(
emp_id int primary key,
emp_name varchar(50)
);

Create table address(
address_id int primary key,
address varchar(500)
);

Create table employee_address(
emp_id int,
address_id int,
/********** this is an extra column **********/
no_of_letters_sent int,

foreign key(emp_id) references employee(emp_id),
foreign key(address_id) references address(address_id)
);
```

How to make hbm.xml files for third table?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add extra columns and keep the many-to-many rel. 
You'll have to switch to many-to-one rels.

See the discussion here:

[Can add extra field(s) to @ManyToMany Hibernate extra table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153409/can-add-extra-fields-to-manytomany-hibernate-extra-table/1168740#1168740)