# Hibernate 4 - Can add extra field(s) to @ManyToMany Hibernate extra table?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have same question which was answered in hibernate 3 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153409/can-add-extra-fields-to-manytomany-hibernate-extra-table). However, I can't apply this to hibernate 4 as there is no @CollectionOfElements annotation. Can someone provide the solution that can be executed using hibernate 4?

EDIT: changed @CollectionOfElements to @ElementCollection worked for me. What should I do with @JoinTable now, because there is no table field in there.

Comment: What about [@ElementCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html)???

Comment: ignore JoinTable, don't need it. You might want @OrderColumn, as necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate 4 only supports the standard JPA annotation, which is [@ElementCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html).

Note that even [Hibernate 3 recommends using this standard annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CollectionOfElements.html):

> Deprecated. use @ElementCollection